# How to add a chr(47) '\' to a string?

Tags: string, lua

```
local html_path = "[[" .. GetPostProcessorLocation()
html_path = html_path .. ????  .. "New Please Register Me.html]]"

chr(47)
"\"
exactly what do you need me to type so as to continue?
```

Comment: It would be good if you could add the actual output you expect. You can use < pre > tag if needed

Comment: `\ ` is used to escape characters you can use `\\ ` to escape the character in the string. Basically double every instance of `\ ` in the path

Answer (score 0):

character `47` is the forward slash (`/`), not the backslash (`\`). The backslash is character `92`. I'm assuming you meant the backslash since the forward slash usually causes no issues.

I'm also not sure what you wanted to achieve with the square brackets (`[[..]]`), since that is actually a way to denote a multiline string in Lua that has no other processing.

Here is hopefully helpful example output from a Lua 5.2 REPL:

```lua
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> function GetPostProcessorLocation() return "C:\\Programs"; end
>
> print("[[" .. GetPostProcessorLocation() .. string.char(92)  .. "New Please Register Me.html]]")
[[C:\Programs\New Please Register Me.html]]
> print(GetPostProcessorLocation() .. string.char(92)  .. [[New Please Register Me.html]])
C:\Programs\New Please Register Me.html
> print(GetPostProcessorLocation() .. [[\New Please Register Me.html]])
C:\Programs\New Please Register Me.html
> print(GetPostProcessorLocation() .. [[\\New Please Register Me.html]])
C:\Programs\\New Please Register Me.html
> -- Note the double-backslash in the output above!
> print(GetPostProcessorLocation() .. "\\New Please Register Me.html")
C:\Programs\New Please Register Me.html
> print(string.format("%s\\%s", GetPostProcessorLocation(), "New Please Register Me.html"))
C:\Programs\New Please Register Me.html
```